# Can I Ask For More Information On Some Rare Short Video Clips I Have?

Tags: discussion

I have some most likely rare video clips that I believe are early HD video tests which I pulled from a hard drive of some test equipment. I would like to know more information about these clips but this seems like I'm starting to head into the identification territory.

I think this could be a very interesting discussion because I'm also interested in the history behind them and if we were able to find out what they were I think it could bring up an interesting discussion on the history and technical aspects of the video clip.

In addition because I have the clips if we find it, is something that can be answered objectively because I'd gladly upload screenshots and even the clip if allowed. I'm not just posting a vague description of something I saw in the 1980s as an example.

I've tried over the years to find more information about these clips including reverse image searches, and when they talk to type in what they are saying and other search queries related to it. For one of them I was even able to identify some of the buildings featured in the video but I was never able to identify the title of many of them despite extensive search engine effort.

I personally believe this would lead to a high quality discussion.

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me *what* "more information" you're looking for here. If you really just want to know what film those clips are from or where they come from, I'm afraid this might indeed be quite inappropriate for the site.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson yes that would be the first step. It could then lead to other questions such as what camera was used and how was it recorded and who made it and why.

Answer (score 1):

Answers to the Photography SE meta question [Can I ask Videography related questions?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28/50110) are "it depends" but one points out that the site [Video Production SE](https://video.stackexchange.com) exists and that might be just the right place for your question!

As an alternative, you might *think about* asking a different but related question in [Retrocomputing SE](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions) as your question has to do with the history of a digital format. It's perfectly fine to ask two different but related questions on different SE sites at the same time and in each question provide a link to the other and a few words noting that the other is different.

Answer (score -2):

Feels like a better fit for Reddit channel https://www.reddit.com/r/whatisthisthing/